# WPBakery toggle stretch row and row with Image Gallery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am using WPBarkery in my Wordpress theme and I have 2 rows, One is a stretch row and the other is a default row but has the element Image Gallery in it.

What I am trying to do is apply two separate toggles for these rows, I have the toggles working like so:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(){
        $('.section1').toggle();
        return false;
});

$('.windows-walls-floors').bind('click', function(){
        $('.section2').toggle();
        return false;
});
```

However when I initially hide these elements like so:

```
.section1 {
    display: none;
}

.section2 {
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is when I goto toggle them, my stretch row and the Image Gallery is messed up. The Image Gallery only shows one image instead of all the images and the stretch row is not full width and all the content in the stretch row is pulled to the left. This is weird, anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem not with display none, height 0px and overflow hidden

```
.vc_section {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.section1.show {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and the jQuery

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(){
            if ($(".section1").hasClass("show")) {
                $('.section1').removeClass('show');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.section1').addClass('show');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Works great with stretch rows and Image Gallery